# Откуда берут информацию о кинотеатрах и показах в них?

Tags: php, api

Собственно существуют различные сайты с информацией о кинотеатрах различных городов и показах в них. Самые крупные известные мне - это кино афиша и кино поиск яндекса. 
Интересует откуда они берут информацию, сомневаюсь что база заполняется в ручную. Существует ли некое свободно доступное API? Или какие есть варианты?

Comment: Общая база скорее всего парсится из данных каждого кинотеатра скорее всего. А они уже забивают руками. Вообще это слишком абстрактрый вопрос.

Comment: Может парсят, да, или может у кинотеатров есть приватное API какое-нибудь. Действительно, вопрос слишком абстрактный. Но вот, например, есть API по второй ссылке из гугла https://kinoplan.ru/products/api

Comment: Не удивлюсь, если кинотеатры сами загружают в них данные, чтобы привлечь больше посетителей.

Comment: Я не знаю как более точно его сформулировать. Допустим мне необходима информация о кинотеатрах в каком либо городе и показах в них. Как я могу получить эти данные? Парсить кинопоиск.... не очень подходящий вариант... Желательно бы получить доступ к этой информации путем подключения к API, но вот к какому и где его найти вопрос. Ну и конечно же безвозмездно

Comment: @D-side больше похоже на правду.

Comment: @AGS17 что значит слишком абстрактный? Есть ведь способы и они совершенно конкретные. Просто вы лично их не знаете)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вопрос я счел абстрактным, потому что вопросописец не предоставил нам никаких данных о том кто берет, в каком формате и тд. Есть много способов парсинга, но вы не сможете ответить какие, потому что **в вопросе нет данных об этом**

Comment: @AGS17 `кто берет` - кино афиша и кино поиск яндекса, очевидно. Это указано в вопросе. Можно также дополнить гуглом на заглавной странице.....`в каком формате` - в каком формате что? ТС, собственно, сам и спрашивает как и откуда, чтобы реализовать подобное. `Есть много способов парсинга` - в вопросе нет ни слова про парсинг

Comment: кмк можно и полтос кинуть на конкурс :) Вопрос интересный. Жаль мало кто обладает сими познаниями в этой области.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, самому интересно.

Comment: я думаю вам товарищи вам куда то [сюда](https://ekinobilet.ru/) надо

Comment: @teran, пректасная ссылка.

Comment: Ну вообще такие сайты предоставляют RSS каналы.Это XML где предоставляется разная информация про продукт .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мой ответ (по крайней мере пока что)  не будет претендовать на ответ, в нужном нам смысле слова, но оставлю некоторые заметки, чтобы не пропали, а кто-то мб пойдет в изучении дальше.

Во-первых, как мы понимаем, государство регулирует рынок кинопроката. Картины допускаются к прокату с разрешения каких-то там комиссий, и соответственно отслеживается что и где показывается. Поэтому, если думаешь, что государство что-то мониторит - гугли *"единая государственная система"*  и добавляй предмет поиска, в нашем случае "[кино](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0+%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0)".

Дальше переходим на сайт "[Электронный кинобилет](https://ekinobilet.ru/)" (видимо какая то первая версия на скорую руку). Тут нам без логина и пароля делать почти нечего.  Однако мы видим, красным шрифтом, что имеется *Программа ручного формирования XML- файлов с информацией о продаже кинобилетов CreateXML*. А также в наличие ссылка на скачивание программы. В архиве есть руководство пользователя. Из руководства видно, что программа написана в [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) (вроде 2009). Введение гласит:

> Предназначена программа для кинотеатров и сетей кинотеатров, не
>   имеющих автоматизированных систем продажи билетов, небольших прокатных
>   организаций, сельских кинотеатров, кинопередвижек и др.
>   Отсюда 2 вывода:

1. Есть автоматизированные системы продажи билетов, которые напрямую самостоятельно отправляют данные по продажам в [ГИВЦ (главный информационно вычислительный центр) МинКультуры](http://givc.ru/about/).
2. Те, кто не может себе позволить такую роскошь, обязаны заполнять данные вручную с помощью указанной `CreateXML`.

Руководство пользователя писал, очевидно, весьма одаренный человек, иначе я не могу объяснить, как вообще может в голову прийти написать следующий текст к диалогу для указания URL-загрузки файлов (и почему вообще этот URL можно настраивать тоже не ясно):

> В данной закладке задаются адреса, по которым осуществляется от-правка
>   XML-файлов. Эти адреса заданы по умолчанию и **не рекомендуется с ними
>   экспериментировать.**

Далее, зная название системы можно заглянуть в [википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B), где в копилку знаний можно добавить следующее:

> В России отслеживанием кассовых сборов занимается Фонд Кино.
>   Отраслевая аналитика строится на основе данных Единой Федеральной
>   автоматизированной информационной системы сведений о показах фильмов в
>   кинозалах (ЕАИС).

Переходим на сайт [ЕАИС](http://ekinobilet.fond-kino.ru/). Можем посмотреть [ютуб-ролик](http://ekinobilet.fond-kino.ru/about/history/). Видим, что есть приложение, следовательно, скорее всего есть API, публичный или закрытый - не ясно. Упоминаний про API на сайте не видно. [Разработчики сайта](http://www.kingbird.ru/) скорее всего могут дать больше информации по данному вопросу. На странице [Статистика-Прокат](http://ekinobilet.fond-kino.ru/statistics/generate-report/) можно какие-то отчеты выгружать в Excel. Который в принципе уже поддается обработке, как и парсинг самой страницы.

Следующий этап - узнать про API, тут уж либо гуглить, либо посмотреть, что там мобильное приложение и куда шлет, или сайт куда ajax-запрашивает. Но это за пределами моего сегодняшнего гугло-сеанса. Передаю эстафету.

Comment: Про ЕАИС на сайте  "Электронный кинобилет"  написано.

Answer (score 2):

В развитии кинопроката участвуют все кому эта сфера не безразлична. Особенно она не безразлична [кинодистрибьюторам](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80). 90% этого рынка в России занимают [пять компаний](https://www.filmpro.ru/materials/31307).  Они, к примеру, по роду своей деятельности заинтересованы в расширении аудитории кинозрителей.

Для этого им необходимо заключить договора как отдельно с кинотеатром, так и их сетями, при этом в максимальном количестве населенных пунктов. Кинотеатрам, в свою очередь, с ними. Постепенно накапливается автоматизированная база данных, с которой нужно грамотно работать, а именно продвигать свою продукцию (кино) через рекламу, ТВ и интернет-ресурсы.

И чем шире охват аудитории, качественнее контент , к примеру у Кинопоиска Яндекса, тем эффективней происходит обмен данными между таким ресурсом и дистрибьютором вплоть до свободных мест в отдельно взятом кинотеатре какого-нибудь города в определенный момент времени.

Answer (score 0):

Когда сам владел сайтом с городской киноафишей - кинотеатры сами присылали каждый четверг обновлённую информацию о расписании. 
Сперва нужно было совершить один звонок в кинотеатр, а после этого email добавлялся в общую рассылку и я получал актуальную инфу.
Может и есть какой-то сервис с открытым/закрытым API, но скорее всего база его база заполняется вручную.